# HOW TO SEARCH FROM GOOGLESHEET

Tags: google-sheets, search, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

how are you? this time I want to ask formula in googlesheet how to find data with multiple criteria and the criteria is dropdown for example i insert the sample link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k0a_3LhMnVCiQ0pcOcFBfC7K5O2UAUugaeO6P1vSw7M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY('DATA BASE'!A:F; "where 1=1"&
 IF(B2="";;" and B = '"&B2&"'")&
 IF(C2="";;" and E = '"&C2&"'")&
 IF(D2="";;" and D = '"&D2&"'")&
 IF(E2="";;" and F = "&E2))
```

[image]